# Temporory tables using Spring's jdbc template

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, t-sql, jdbc

I'm facing an issue executing a very long query using spring jdbcTemplate. The query contains multiple `DECLARE` statements, multiple `CREATE` temp tables and in the end a `SELECT` statement which gets data by joining multiple tables as well as `DROP` statements. When I run this query directly in SQL Management studio, the query runs perfectly fine and returns me the data. However when I run the exact same query using spring's jdbc template there is no data returned.

Edit: I can not post exact query I'm using. But below is the template of how the query may look.

```
public class SpringJdbcExample{

        public static final String sql = "DECLARE "+
        "@XYZ DATETIME='1/31/2016', " +
        "@ABC UNIQUEIDENTIFIER='', " +
        "@var1 VARCHAR (1)='F', " +
        "@var2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL " +


        "DECLARE @id1 INT, @id2 INT, @id3 Int "+
        "SELECT @id1=(SELECT id1 FROM table1 WHERE XYZ=@XYZ) "+
        "SELECT @id2=(SELECT id2 FROM table2 WHERE ABC=@ABC) " +

            "SET NOCOUNT ON "+
            "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL    READ UNCOMMITTED "+


            "CREATE TABLE #temp1 (var1 INT, var2 INT, var2 INT, var4 varchar(20) ) "+

            "CREATE TABLE #temp2 (var1 INT,var2 INT, var3 DATETIME, var4 varchar(20)) "+

        -- More Create temp tables

        -- Insert into temp tables from various DB tables

    -- single Select statement from temp tables

    -- Drop temp tables
    "; // end of the string

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public SpringJdbcExample (JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public List<String> getData(){
    // MapSqlParameterSource
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("someParams", "someValues");
    jdbcTemplate.query(sql,params);
    }
```

Comment: post the query and the code of spring template

Comment: All of that in a single JdbcTemplate call? You mean, many statements separated by semicolon?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then come back here to improve your question. In short add some code and context.

Comment: @Raffaele: yes all that in a single JdbcTemplate call.

Comment: @user2067733 So you'd better use a stored procedure and wrap it in a subclass of  [`StoredProcedure`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html)

Comment: @Raffaele, yes that option is there. I wanted to understand why this as a single query wouldn't work in this case :-).

Comment: Without any error message, how one can tell...

Comment: Because it isn't a single query it are multiple. What you want is to execute them on the same connection. However you fail to add the requested code on how you try to execute this with a `JdbcTemplate`.